# Color nodes in directed network in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed network with only two type of nodes, A and B.The direction is always **from any given A**, **to any given B**. No other direction is possible.

Edge list looks like this:

`edges <- read.table(text = "
from to weight
1 6 1.2
3 7 1.4
4 6 1.2
1 7 1.2
2 8 1.2
1 9 1.2
5 10 1.2 ", header=T )`

Nodes list looks like this:

```
nodes
id 
1  1   
2  1   
3  3  
4  4   
5  5  
6  6    
7  7    
8  B
9  9
10 10
```

The graph is created using the igraph package.

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices=nodes, directed = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to color nodes based on whether they are **from** or **to** in the edgeslist, without adding other variables/labels to the nodeslist?

(I tried coloring nodes like so, but realized it does not make much sense)

```
plot(g, vertex.color=V(g$edges=='from'))
```

Comment: in your example 6 is in both "from" and "to" categories, same for 7.

Comment: @desval thanks, I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I think what you are looking for doesn't really exist. `vertex.color` needs a vector of colors, one color for each of the vertices.

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use the output of degree to select vertices with in (or out) degree of 0 or higher:

```
plot(g,
     vertex.color=ifelse(degree(g, mode = "out")>0, "red", "black"),
     size=15)
```